# Call a particular function before and after each function execution

Tags: javascript, function

I need to call a particular function before and after each function execution

For example
I have these functions

```
function a() {
    // logic
}

function b() {
    // logic
}

function c() {
    // logic
}
```

what I am doing now is

```
function a(){
    c();
    // logic
    c();
}

function b(){
    c();
    // logic
    c();
}
```

is there are better way for doing this something like advice in Spring

Comment: If you are using ES6 why not use reflection ?

Comment: I think it is simple and easy to read enough. You just call `a()` or `b()` and it's done.

Comment: might the original functions also require parameters to be passed to them?

Comment: yes, some of the functions have parameters

Comment: If you are using `$.ajax` within function then you can use promise.
that will really help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could just define a "higher-order" helper function like this:

```
function wrapWith(baseFunc, otherFunc) {
    function wrapper() {
        otherFunc();
        baseFunc();
        otherFunc();
    }
    return wrapper;
}
```

Then just define `a = wrapWith(a, c)`, `b = wrapWith(b, c)`, etc. (And if you sometimes will need the "unwrapped" `a` and `b`, just assign the wrapped versions to new variables rather than overwriting `a` and `b`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a wrapper function which accepts these two functions as parameter and execute in a order you want.

```
const wrapper = (logic, advice)=>{
advice();
let log  = logic()
advice()
return log
}
```

then call it as

```
wrapper(a,c)
wrapper (b,c);
```